# Java Reflection ArrayList.class.getMethod("get") returns NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, reflection, arraylist, nosuchmethoderror

Why can't I get the "get" method of an ArrayList and invoke it?

I am using reflection to modify within my nested classes. One of my classes has a list of classes so I wanted to be able to use the same logic to get and invoke the get method.

simplified, the line that fails is

```
ArrayList.class.getClass().getMethod("get")
```

and it fails, giving me a NoSuchMethodException.

I understand that I could use aList.get() but that's not the point, I need to use reflection since this is in a deeply nested class.

**TL;DR
How can I get the "get" method of an array list?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that [`Class#getMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) has two parameters: a `String` and an vararg of `Class` objects. The former is

> the list of parameters

that the method declares.

You need to use

```
ArrayList.class.getMethod("get", int.class);
```

since the `ArrayList#get(int)` method has an `int` parameter.

---

I initially missed the whole

```
ArrayList.class.getClass().getMethod("get")
          ^     ^ 
          |     |----------------------------- gets Class<Class>
          |----------------------------------- gets Class<ArrayList>
```

The `.class` already gets the `Class` instance for `ArrayList`. Calling `getClass` on that will return the `Class` instance for class `Class`. You don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

```
Method methods = ArrayList.class.getMethod("get", int.class);
```

You do not need to call getClass() method again after .class because when you write .class after a class name, it references the Class object that represents the given class.